# Creating a wireless water level indicator and/ or controller

Tags: water, remote-control, indicator

I wish to create a wireless water level indicator for measuring the level of water in my sump and then making automatic changes to the motor switch to fill the water to the overhead tank. What are the tools required to do so. In the market online, I find very less wireless options available. The float sensors are all wired, and are quite expensive. Is there a DIY solution to this?

I think installing two electrodes with a powered battery, with an alert occurring in my smart phone ( or a similar alarming system) is the way to go. For this, I think I need to have a bluetooth installed  in the provisional sensor. As for remote controlling the switch of the water motor, I think I have to somehow modify the available controller in the market which works for wired sensors. Any ideas how this could be done from scratch. I am a total beginner in this. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic but it sounds like a good arduino micro controller project.

Comment: Perhaps this question is better asked over at the “Internet of things”  stack  exchange

Comment: A basic float won't do?

Comment: Wireless tank level sensors exist - buy one and re-purpose or take apart and understand how it works then re-purpose re-design to suit your needs.

Comment: @SolarMike yes, i have seen that those are available. But the cost and non-availability in this covid time are the real issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Arduino would fit the bill here except for the difficulty and also expense of adding WiFi connectivity to it.  Wifi "hats" are fairly expensive.

Let me suggest that a Raspberry Pi Zero W is probably the easiest way to make your own IoT device that will keep track of your water level and give you an easy way to check on it or send an alarm.

Here is an example project:

[Pi Water Level](https://www.hackster.io/shafin-kothia/water-level-monitor-with-raspberry-pi-d509a2)